# Why won't CVS allow user login (on a Synology server)?

Tags: synology, cvs

I'm trying to set up a CVS server on my synology NAS, but am getting a recurring error in actually accessing the cvs via login. I'm also posting this on the synology server, but thought that I'd post here as it's probably more of a CVS issue than a Synology issue.

I followed these instructions to set up CVS http://forum.synology.com/wiki/index.php/Step-by-step_guide_to_installing_CVS_server

Here's the result of login:

> $ cvs -d :pserver:user1@redacted.org:/opt/cvsroot login
>
> cvs login: authorization failed: server redacted.org rejected access to /opt/cvsroot for user user1

Results of various checks:

> $ Netstat -l | grep cvs
>
> tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:cvspserver 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN

..

> $ cat /etc/services | grep cvs
>
> cvspserver 2401/tcp # CVS client/server operations
>
> cvspserver 2401/udp # CVS client/server operations
>
> cvsup 5999/tcp CVSup # CVSup file transfer/John Polstra/FreeBSD
>
> cvsup 5999/udp CVSup # CVSup file transfer/John Polstra/FreeBSD

Synology details :: DS2411+ DSM 4.1-2661

The password I'm using is correct per /opt/cvsroot/CVSROOT/passwd Permissions on passwd are chmod 400, and owned by cvs:cvs.

Any thoughts? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be the synology needs the CVS port opened on it.  TCP and UDP ports must be open for CVS.  Port # is 2401.

[Synology Firewall Port Forwarding Setup Page](http://www.synology.com/support/tutorials_show.php?q_id=456)